# How do thresholds affect true shapeshifters with modular abilities?

Tags: dresden-files, thresholds

How would a threshold affect characters with the True Shapeshifting power? Would it prevent them from shifting once past the threshold (uninvited)? And would the threshold affect their Modular Abilities? I.E. Would a +2 threshold remove 2 refresh worth of their Modular Abilities?

Any input would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

EDIT: I wanted to add a bit of info about the exact situation for the game I'm running. The player character is a Changeling of a Fetch. It's a submerged campaign and for his powers he has taken True Shapeshifting [-4], Human Form [+1], and Modular Abilities [-6].

Comment: So, I hope I answered your question in general. If you've still got any specific questions left, please let me know.

Comment: The PC commonly uses the Modular Abilities for various levels of the Speed/Strength/Toughness/Recovery powers depending on the situation at hand. 

From what I'm reading it seems that since once he's shapeshifted he's a physical body a threshold wouldn't affect that. So mainly it's about the Modular Abilities. I think it may be best to do like you said and go case by case depending on the powers. I.E. a wolf with "Inhuman" Speed might not be affected as that power is reflective of a wolf having that capability. But if he had "Supernatural" Speed the threshold may issue a drawback of some kind.

Comment: I would strongly suggest converting this to an overview question and creating an entirely new question. It'll get more attention and we can help you shape it better now that we know more about what you're asking; or rather, not asking. Specifically, this is the sort of question where its best to outline what actually happened during gameplay that made you want to know the answer. It allows people to apply their GM expertise to the problem rather than just helping you interpret the rules.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**They don't. Mostly.**

Everything you need to answer this question is found in **Thresholds** section, starting on YS230. Like a lot of things in Dresden Files and Fate games in general, it comes down to "What's going on in the narrative?"

---

**What's a Threshold?**

There's a big difference between Thresholds and Wards, even though Wards are built on top Thresholds. Strictly speaking, thresholds are:

> The barrier that is formed around a home by the simple act of people living in it and regarding it as a place of safety, shelter, and family.

Murphy's house is a good example of an average threshold. However, there other things that are commonly thought of, or mechanically count as, thresholds.

> In the broadest sense, the term "threshold" may be given to any metaphysical barrier that impedes or blocks supernatural power from passing from point A to point B.

Running water, sunrises, and magic circles are all examples found in the books.

Wards, on the other hand, are sets of spells built on top of the threshold. These can be additional protections, alarms, or traps and are usually what's going on when a baddie can't get into Dresden's place.

---

**So, what does this mean for shapeshifters?**

> Some beings - especially those of pure spirit - cannot cross a threshold, since they're usually using their magical power to hold their material world body together. [....] When an entity crosses a threshold in a mystically manufactured body, most of the entity's power goes toward holding it all together, limiting it to what its body can physically do.

One of the first and most obvious things this means is that unless your shapeshifter is pure spirit or a being with a specific ban, they can cross the threshold with impunity in a purely physical sense. If a spirit being wants to cross the threshold, they'll have to destroy it first.

The next and more important thing this means is that any abilities not native to the form are subject to the suppressive and/or blocking effects of magic, subject to your GM's interpretation of the rules. This is the same reason that Dresden can't use magic effectively when he crosses a threshold without permission. A wolf might reasonably possess Claws and Inhuman Speed. But Supernatural Speed says it right in the name. Any benefits would be subject to suppression.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I added some details about the PC for clarity.

Answer (score -2):

A big question would be what kind of shape shifter you were. But we'll assume a naagloshi for simplicity. Looking at his attack on the (spoiler)

> Raith household

... I'd think no, that naagloshi seemed completely free to change shape at will while intruding on the house. He didn't do much the way of spell slinging though so it's a safe bet that his magic was weakened. If in a game a GM should decide that a threshold is a serious barrier to a shape shifter you might consider the modular point restriction you mentioned above (though I would recommend it only being -1 mod points for every 2 strength the threshold has).

Or you might consider a discipline or conviction roll against the threshold for the shape shifter.  In the case of the naagloshi it is a pretty vile supernatural hitter. By beating the threshold he forces his way past it unhampered (though his magic is weaker if not shut down) but also weakens the threshold by however much he beat it to represent the metaphysical stain he leaves on the place.

Just a few thoughts though. Shapeshifters that draw their power from other sources might be affected in totally different ways of at all.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I added some details about the PC for clarity.

Comment: I don't think the Raith 'household' counts.  It's less a house, more a mansion cum office building.  (See having mercenaries on hand to die against Shagnasty)  As a result, it's threshold is going to be so weak as to verge on non-existant.  (The same reason Dresden can usually enter a crime scene without an issue)